# Using command prompt (cmd.exe) to "open new window" in explorer at a specific path under the same process in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, command-line, windows-explorer

**NOTE**: This is ***NOT*** a question about opening a cmd prompt window instance in the current explorer folder path.

I've scoured the internet trying to find an answer to this, but have come up empty. So far, I know I can open new explorer windows under the same explorer process via cmd simply by entering the "explorer" command. But if I type in a folder path, either after the explorer command, or on its own, or after the "start" command, the window takes longer to open, and launches in a new explorer process.

My question is: how do I open a new window at a specific folder path in explorer via cmd prompt ***under the same process as the currently running explorer.exe instance*** - basically, the same way I would via <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> from an open explorer window, then entering the path in the address bar, or right-clicking a folder in explorer and selecting "open in new window".

I really hope someone can answer this. I'm sure it's relatively simple, and I've been racking my brain trying to figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I type in a folder path it opens in the same Explorer window, which seems different from your experience. Perhaps the difference is in *View > Options > Open each folder in the same window*.

Comment: @harrymc no, you missed the part where I said I wanted to use command prompt to launch a new window in explorer, under the same explorer process - not by launching a new explorer process. Not the same as typing a path into the address bar in an explorer window.

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: Easy enough from **PowerShell** using the `shell.application` com object. What has you wedded to `cmd.exe`?

Comment: @harrymc TMI to explain here. Suffice it to say it would help relieve some major pains in my workflow.

Comment: @KeithMiller because I have 0 experience with powerShell, and kind of hate it. lol. but if you can answer and explain how I could do this using powerShell, and I can script AHK to launch that with a hotkey, that'd solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one command that you may enter in Explorer that will open the folder
`C:\Temp` in the same instance of `explorer.exe`:

```
powershell.exe -command Invoke-Item C:\Temp
```

For related reading:

- [PowerShell command](https://ss64.com/ps/powershell.html)
- [PowerShell Invoke-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/invoke-item?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: I'm not at the PC right now to try this, but could I add the same command on several lines (each specifying a different path, and separated by a ping command), and save it as a batch file that I could run to open several new explorer windows under the same process? BTW, nice OG Tron avatar, user! :)

Comment: Yes, according to my tests this will work for multiple folders and from a batch file.