# command line to have windows explorer open folder in existing instance of explorer

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-explorer, windows-11

I frequently use `explorer .` from a command line to open windows explorer in the current directory.  It would be nice to be able to do this as a new tab in a previously open instance of explorer instead of as a totally new window.  Is there a way to do this?  None of the command line options I've found do this and `explorer /?` doesn't work. I'm running windows 11 for what it's worth.

[Using command prompt (cmd.exe) to "open new window" in explorer at a specific path under the same process in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1714879/using-command-prompt-cmd-exe-to-open-new-window-in-explorer-at-a-specific-pa) appears to be more or less the same question, but running `invoke-item .` opens the current folder in a new instance.

Explorer is set to open folders in the same window:

[image]

Comment: Not really possible unless you are willing to kill all existing instances. It technically still opens a new window, but if you only had one window open, it will not create clutter. Downside is that the window position will still move. Another option could be to use another file explorer that does allow you to do this. I don't know of any though...